# Browse media library not opening

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-media-library

We are using Sitecore 6.5 and the Browse link on images within the CMS backend is not opening up the window to select an image. A blank window just appears.

There is nothing in the Sitecore logs or window event logs. This used to work - when I compare the bin folders with the previous version, I only see a difference in the version of mscorlib.dll

I don't know if this is related, but when uploading a package we get the error

```
[ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes() +9
   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes() +143
```

Comment: Can you check if you have javascript erros on your browser ?

Comment: there are no javascript errors ... Im suspecting it's due to a dll issue as this used to work before an extra site was added to an existing site within a project...

Comment: I've done a file compare with the version that works on the bin folder. Only difference is mscorlib.dll so maybe it's a web.config issues..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the \sitecore\shell\applications\Media\MediaBrowser\MediaBrowser.xml  file was complete empty.

We have no idea how this happened. Restoring the xml fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen something similar to this when the source path specified on the field was set to an invalid folder.  If you take a look at the field definitions on the template, do they have a folder specified for the image location? Is that folder still valid?

Comment: Path looks good and removing the path in the template or changing it doesnt fix this one ...